# How to do this with list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples that I want to convert to integers using a dictionary, I think this can be done in one line
but cant figure it out and I am instead using explicit for loops, anyone know how?

```
edge_list=[('D','G'),('E','D'),('E','G'),
           ('C','E'),('B','D'),('A','C'),('A','B'),('C','D'),('G','F')]

map={'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4,'E':5,'F':6,'G':7}

int_edges=[]

for edge in edge_list:
    new_pair=[]
    for val in edge:
        new_pair.append(map[val])
    int_edges.append(new_pair)

#result (int_edges=[[4, 7], [5, 4], [5, 7], [3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 6]])
```

Comment: Would you like to share what you've tried and what errors you got?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can do it with a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
int_edges = [(map[a], map[b]) for a, b in edge_list]
```

Think of it like this:

For each pair `(a, b)` in `edge_list` you want a new pair that has value `(map[a], map[b])`. In a classic `for` loop you would write it as follows:

```py
for a, b in edge_list:
    int_edges.append((map[a], map[b]))
```

Reverse the order of the `for` and its body, remove the `append` and you have the list comprehension you want!

---

**Side note**: `map` is the name of a built-in Python function. Avoid using it as variable name. Use something else, such as `edge_map` instead.